# Iptables conditional internal redirection

Tags: linux, iptables, redirect

I want to make iptables redirect internally from one port to another only if a service is listening to that port. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK IPtables doesn't have enough information to do that effectively.  You would probably need to write a script that uses netcat or data from netstat to decide if the port is listening, and if so do the redirect.  Run that script from cron.

Comment: You think a pid or a lock file would help? Maybe using conntrack or state matching modules?

Comment: Don't force yourself to use iptables. You can check with a `if` command from `netstat`, `lsof`, ... result and do the redirect.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can do it:

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ethx
>   -p tcp --dport $srcPort -j REDIRECT --to-port $dstPort

Comment: That's what I already have, but that doesn't make sure a service is listening or that the port is on a certain state.